# How to deal with distinction of parameters in Java?

Tags: java

I need a method that expects different parameters, and behave differently depending on the parameters, like in this example:

```
public void doSomething(A a, B b, C c) {
    doSomeGeneralStuff();

    if a.isPresent() {
        doSomethingWithA();
    }
    if b.isPresent() {
        doSomethingWithB();
    }
    if c.isPresent() {
        doSomethingWithC();
    }
}
```

An alternative would be this:

```
public void doSomething(A a) {
    doSomeGeneralStuff();
    doSomethingWithA();
}
public void doSomething(B b) {
    doSomeGeneralStuff();
    doSomethingWithB();
}
public void doSomething(C c) {
    doSomeGeneralStuff();
    doSomethingWithC();
}
```

But I would have a bunch of redundant code in the second example, that's why I'm still not satisfied. What other patterns deal with this problem?

Comment: Why would you have redundant code? The only 'redundant' code is you need to call doSomeGeneralStuff() in each doSomething() method.

Comment: Add `doSomeGeneralStuff()` into the method of `A,B and C`?

Comment: Putting generic code into its own method and calling it from more specialised methods is not a bad thing, so I wouldn't call that redundant.

Comment: In your first code, you call the `doSomeGeneralStuff` once even if you have two or three parameters where `isPresent` returns true. In your second code, it seems you'll need to call `doSomething` three times in such a case, and therefore `doSomeGeneralStuff` will be called three times. Is that what you mean when you say "redundant code"? Or did you miss this difference in semantics?

Answer (score 8):

You can use inheritance.  Have a common interface for all of `A`, `B` and `C`.

```
public void doSomething(Common abc) {
    doSomeGeneralStuff();
    abc.doSomethingWithABC();
}

interface Common {
    void doSomethingWithABC();
}

class A implements Common {

class B implements Common {

class C implements Common {
```

Answer (score 1):

I am upvoting Peter Lawrey's answer and suggesting this alternative:

```
public void doSomething(Object o) {
    doSomeGeneralStuff();

    if (o instanceof A) {
        doSomethingWithA(o);
    }
    if (o instanceof B) {
        doSomethingWithB(o);
    }
    if (o instanceof C) {
        doSomethingWithC(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass a type as the `parameter` , something like

```
private void doSomething(Class<?> cls) {
    if (cls == String.class) { doSomething1();
}
    else if (cls == int.class) { doSomething2();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Design an *interface* `I`, which declares `doSomething` and adjust your classes A, B, and C to *implement* that interface:

`class A implements I`, etc.

Then refactor `doSomething` to exploit a *variable argument list*:

```
void doSomething(I... eyes)
{
    for (i : eyes){
        doSomeGeneralStuff()
        i.doSomething();
    }    
}
```

You can call `doSomething` with any number of objects, so long as they implement `I`: for example, `doSomething(a)`, `doSomething(a, b)`, `doSomething(a, b, c)` etc.